# Expected distance between points drawn from different distributions

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, with $X_1,X_2$ being independent copies of $X$ and $Y_1,Y_2$ being independent copies of $Y$. Then (is it true that)

$2\mathbb{E}|X-Y|\geq\mathbb{E}|X_1-X_2|+\mathbb{E}|Y_1-Y_2|$?

This is saying that the expected distance between two points drawn from different distributions is greater than the expected distance between points drawn from one or the other.

My attempts so far include:

- *Triangle inequality* gives $4\mathbb{E}|X-Y|\geq\mathbb{E}|X_1-X_2|+\mathbb{E}|Y_1-Y_2|$ when we write $|X_1-X_2|=|(X_1-Y_1)+(Y_1-X_2)|$;
- *Squared distances* work, i.e. $2\mathbb{E}(X-Y)^2\geq\mathbb{E}(X_1-X_2)^2+\mathbb{E}(Y_1-Y_2)^2$ holds immediately after expanding the squares;
- *Counterexamples?* I have tried generating $X$, $Y$ from different distributions, e.g. normal, exponential, simple Bernoulli, etc. and haven't found anything. However, the inequality very much doesn't hold for $X$ and $Y$ dependent - a trivial example is $Y=X$, when the LHS is 0 while the RHS can be positive.
- *Discrete case* doesn't seem to shed much more light on it. The inequality reduces to $\sum_{i,j} (p_i-q_i)(p_j-q_j)|i-j|\leq 0$, where $p_i=\mathbb{P}(X=i)$ and $q_i=\mathbb{P}(Y=i)$.

I have also thought of Jensen for $|x|, \sqrt{x},x^2$, Holder ($||fg||_1\leq ||f||_p||g||_q$ for $1/p+1/q=1$), and Minkowski ($||f+g||_p\leq||f||_p+||g||_p$ for $p\geq 1$).

I would appreciate any ideas/counterexamples/references for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are your random variables real-valued? Your question makes sense when they take value in any metric space; and it would be interesting that the the smallest constant one can put in the right-hand-side (which you expect to be 2) could depends on the space.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner : I have added a remark addressing, in part, your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of me trying to prove the identity in Brendan McKay's answer. Consider, a bit more generally, any nonnegative independent r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$, still with $X_1,X_2$ being independent copies of $X$ and $Y_1,Y_2$ being independent copies of $Y$. Then $P(X\wedge Y>x)=F(x)G(x)$ for all real $x$, where $F(x):=P(X>x)$ and $G(x):=P(Y>x)$. So, 
\begin{equation}
 E(X\wedge Y)=\int_0^\infty dx\,P(X\wedge Y>x)
 =\int_0^\infty dx\,F(x)G(x). 
\end{equation}
Similarly, $E(X_1\wedge X_2)=\int_0^\infty dx\,F(x)^2$  and $E(Y_1\wedge Y_2)=\int_0^\infty dx\,G(x)^2$. 
Note also that $|x-y|=x+y-2(x\wedge y)$ for real $x,y$. 
It follows that 
\begin{equation}
 2E|X-Y|-(E|X_1-X_2|+E|Y_1-Y_2|)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
=-2\int_0^\infty dx\,[2F(x)G(x)-(F(x)^2+G(x)^2)]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
 =2\int_0^\infty dx\,[F(x)-G(x)]^2\ge0. 
\end{equation}

Comment: Thinking about the nonnegativity condition: Since the inequality is unchanged by adding the same constant to both $X$ and $Y$, the result holds if $X$ and $Y$ are bounded on the left.  But then I guess the general case follows by considering a truncation point that goes to $-\infty$, with convergence following from the existence of the expectations.  But I didn't work out the details.

Comment: I had this in mind. My other answer does not need the nonnegativity restriction and hence does not require work on the limit transition.

Comment: My main problem with writing up a general argument like that was that I (was convinced that I) couldn't get into the modulus sign; however the identity $|x-y|=x+y-2(x \wedge y)$ totally solves that problem and it works out beautifully. Many thanks!

Comment: I am of course glad to see that this answer has been recognized. However, it seems strange to me that my other answer to this question, which is much more informative and (I believe) more elegant, has obtained no apparent recognition. Would anyone care to comment on this? Anyhow, I have now made the other answer more detailed and yet more general.

Comment: That's because I have yet to read it in detail.
This problem is part of some interdisciplinary work so my (immediate) focus would be on the more elementary approach.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the discrete nonnegative case, using your notation,
$$\sum_{i,j} (p_i-q_i)(p_j-q_j)|i-j| 
= -2 \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{j=0}^i p_j - \sum_{j=0}^i q_j\right)^2
\le 0,$$
where there are hopefully no convergence problems.

Comment: There seems to be some issues with the indices (a $j$ instead of a $i$ on the left-hand side, and there are no $j$ on the right-hand side). I am not completely sure what you mean.

Comment: @Benoît   Thanks, it is hopefully fixed now.

Comment: Thank you! For future readers, in getting from the lhs to the rhs I found it helpful to introduce a dummy summation index going from i to j instead of the (j-i) factor, and then used identites like $\sum_{i=j+1}^\infty (p_i-q_i)=-\sum_{i=0}^j (p_i-q_i)$ to manipulate the sum ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Take any real $p\ge0$. 
Assume that $E|X|^p+E|Y|^p<\infty$ and $0^0:=1$. For $p>2$, assume also that $EX=EY$. 
Let 
\begin{equation*}
 D_p:=2E|X-Y|^p-(E|X_1-X_2|^p+E|Y_1-Y_2|^p). 
\end{equation*}
The inequality in question can then be stated as $D_1\ge0$.

Let us show, more generally, that 
\begin{equation}
 D_p\ge0\text{ for }p\in[0,2],\quad D_p\le0\text{ for }p\in[2,4]. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
By continuity, without loss of generality $p$ is not an integer. 
So, in the proof that follows let assume that $p\in(0,4)\setminus\{1,2,3\}$.

Then, by formula (4) in [Positive-part moments via the Fourier-Laplace transform. J. Theoret. Probab. 24 (2011), no. 2, 409--421] or at \url{https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.4214}, 
\begin{equation*}
 E|Z|^p=EZ_+^p+E(-Z)_+^p
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*} 
 =\frac{2\Gamma(p+1)}{\pi}\,\cos\frac{(p+1)\pi}2\,
 \int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{t^{p+1}}\Big(\Re h(t)
 -\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\ell/2\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^jt^{2j}}{(2j)!}\,EZ^{2j}\Big), 
\end{equation*}
where $Z$ is any random variable with $E|Z|^p<\infty$, $h$ is the characteristic function (c.f.) of $Z$, and $\ell:=\lceil p-1\rceil$.

Since $p<4$, we have $\ell\le3$ and hence $\lfloor\ell/2\rfloor\le1$. 
Moreover, if $p<2$, then $\ell\le1$ and hence $\lfloor\ell/2\rfloor\le0$. 
Letting $f$ and $g$ denote the c.f.'s of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, we see that the c.f.'s of $X-Y, X_1-X_2,Y_1-Y_2$ are $f\bar g,|f|^2,|g|^2$, respectively. 
Note also that $D_0=0$. Also, $D_2=0$ in the case $p>2$, because in that case we assumed that $EX=EY$. It follows that 
\begin{equation*}
 D_p\overset{\text{sign}}=
 \cos\frac{(p+1)\pi}2\,
 \int_0^\infty\frac{\delta(t)dt}{t^{p+1}}
\end{equation*}
where $\overset{\text{sign}}=$ denotes the equality in sign and 
\begin{equation*}
\delta:= 2\Re(f\bar g)-|f|^2-|g|^2. 
\end{equation*}
Note that $\delta\le0$, since $2\Re(f\bar g)\le2|fg|\le|f|^2+|g|^2$. 
So, excluding the case when $D_p=0$, we conclude that 
\begin{equation*}
 D_p\overset{\text{sign}}=-\cos\frac{(p+1)\pi}2, 
\end{equation*}
which is the same as $(1)$.

It also follows -- see e.g. The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 123, No. 5 (May 2016), pp. 491-496 or \url{https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00537} --  that the inequality 
\begin{equation}
 2E\|X-Y\|\ge E\|X_1-X_2\|+E\|Y_1-Y_2\|
\end{equation}
holds, in particular, when $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors in a Euclidean space or in any two-dimensional normed space.